# Fixed div coming down while scrolling in mobile screen - html / css

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm developing a phone-gap application and testing it on 3 android devices. Some codes are:

**Main area:**

```
<body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">        

                <div class="banner"></div>

                <div id="another_div">Welcome</div>

                <div class="blank_div"></div>
                 <img src="img/connecting2.png" alt="Loading..." id="loading"/>

            <div data-role="footer" class="footer_div">

            </div><!--Footer-->     
        </div>
    </body>
```

**Some css:**

```
.banner
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height:40%;
    max-height:40%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FF0;

}
#now_play_div
{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    font-size:1.5em;
    position:fixed;
    height:7%;
    display:block;
    background:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    top:30%;
    padding-top:1%;
    -webkit-marquee: auto medium infinite scroll normal;   
    overflow-x: -webkit-marquee;

    border-radius:10px;

}
.blank_div
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height:41%;
    max-height:41%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;

}
.footer_div
{

    color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;
    height:10%;
    display:block;
    background:#46639d;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0px;
    padding:1%;
}
```

Now the `banner` is fixed. `blank_div` is used so that my main content doesn't go under the fixed banner. After some work the loading image will be gone and filled with some dynamic content. I can scroll that content but my banner and footer is fixed. `another_div` is fixed too.

This system works perfectly on Sony ericsson(android version:2.3) and symphony(android version:4.0.4). But fails to work properly on Google nexus 7(Android: 4.3) **In nexus while I scroll my main content that is dynamically loaded just under the blank_div the banner started to fall down.** WEIRD!!!!!! While my contents go up, banner comes down. But in other 2 devices it works just fine. **Does anybody know what's wrong?? Or what I'm missing?**

Comment: Try giving left:0 position.

Comment: @Era Worked. What just happened? Can you tell me why this didn't worked before in Nexus? And a big Thanks to you :)

Comment: Don't know but sometimes we need to add all the necessary properties in css for absolute and fixed positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess no more answer will come. So here is the answer which I found from @Era's comment.

```
.banner
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height:40%;
    max-height:40%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FF0;

}
```